# Difference between azure evenhub plugin and Filebeat azure module

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, azure-eventhub, filebeat

I am trying to deploy elkstack on azure with eventhub in between for resiliency.
To ship data from Eventhub to Logstash, I found 2 options azure evenhub plugin and azure module in filebeat.
Not sure which one should I use and in which scenario. Also not able to understand the difference between the working of these 2.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat EH plugin is in Beta and provides less configuration options compared to Logstash plugin. Both plugins implements event processor host consumer model. I would recommend Logstash.